# Etymology of $\mathbf{B}G$ for category of one object for $G$?

Tags: category-theory, notation, terminology

Emily Riehl's book "Category theory in Context" uses the notation $\mathbf{B}G$ for the one object category whose objects is a single object $*$ and whose arrows correspond to group elements. Why is the notation $\mathbf{B}G$ used? Where does $\mathbf{B}$ come from?

Comment: I think it is related to the notation $BG$ for the classifying space of a group, where $B$, I believe, stands for "bundle". See  https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping#delooping_of_a_group_to_a_groupoid and the linked topics there.

Comment: @RobArthan could you please elaborate what the bundle is? I'd be happy to accept an answer!

Comment: @RobArthan Actually, $B$ stands for _base_. The bundle is denoted by $E$, and the fibre by $F$, hence the "fibre sequence" $F \to E \to B$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: you are right. I am writing up a (not very good) answer at the OP's request including a correction to that mistake.

Comment: @ZhenLin: P.S., I wouldn't call $E$ the "bundle": it's the total space of the bundle - for me, the bundle is really the map from $E$ to $B$. Do you know if I am right that it $E$stands for "ensemble"? (I don't have the right books to hand.)

Comment: $E$ stands for _espace (total)_.

Comment: @ZhenLin: thanks. I'll fix my answer.

Comment: I belong to the (rare?) species of category theorists who call the one-object category corresponding to a group (or monoid) $G$ just by $G$. Several advantages: 1) Less notation, 2) the notation reflects that monoids are really just special cases of categories, 3) the notation $BG$ is already used for a *topological space*, not a category, and it's always better to not overload notations.

Comment: @ZhenLin: Do you have any written sources that would confirm the stated etymologies for E and B?  I've also heard that B stands for "bar construction".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is traditional to use the notation $F \to E \to B$ for the spaces involved in a [fibre bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_bundle). Here, I believe $F$ stands for "fibre", $E$ stands for the French term "espace total" ("total space" in English), and $B$ stands for "base space" (not "bundle" - my comment was wrong). For any group $G$ there is an important fibre bundle (actually a [principal $G$-bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_bundle)) $F \to EG \to BG$, where $F = G$, $EG$ is contractible and $BG$ is called the [classifying space of $G$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classifying_space), which, in a certain sense, represents all principal $G$-bundles. The construction of $BG$ from $G$ can be generalised to categories other than the category of topological spaces, see this article on [delooping](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/delooping#delooping_of_a_group_to_a_groupoid). The notation $BG$ seems to have been adopted from the special case of the classifying space in topology.

Acknowledgments to Zhen Lin for valuable corrections.